# rugarch - Use loop for to get AIC of servaral models in R

Tags: r

In package rugarch,

I want to list out the AIC of several garch models in R.
But I don't know how to to :(, So I use the loop for to get the infocriteria of them. my code below:

```
for(i in 1:5)
  {
  for(j in 1:5)
    {
    garch11.spec=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(i,j)))
    garch11.fit=ugarchfit(spec=garch11.spec, data=google_rets)
    print(infocriteria(garch11.fit))
    }
  }
```

After running 2 models, an error occupts:

```
Error in itestm[1, 1] <- itest$AIC : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .sgarchfit(spec = spec, data = data, out.sample = out.sample,  : 
ugarchfit-->warning: solver failer to converge.
2: In log(log(nObs)) : NaNs produced
```

How can I solve the error?

Could you give me a way to get the AIC from package rugrach

Comment: Please share your data using `dput` so others can help. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `auto.arima()` and `arimaorder()` to get the `p,d,q` values and fit into the `ugarchspec()`, it will be more effcient than using for loop...

You can use google translate and refer to [binary.com 面试试题 I - GARCH模型中的ARIMA(p,d,q)参数最优化](https://rpubs.com/englianhu/binary-Q1FiGJRGARCH) for more information.